# How to open a 32 bit Access mdb file from within a 64 bit Excel Add In

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, 64-bit, excel-addins

I need to know how to open a 32 bit Access MDB file from within a 64 bit Excel VBA Add-In. There is a great deal of information on the internet but no complete specific examples with code. I am just looking for an example.

I am running a Excel (64bit) and have installed the Office 2010 AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe to get the appropriate Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 drivers.

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=" & dbPlanFile & "; "
```

The dbPlanFile is valid.

I have tried various combinations of the following connection string to no avail.

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=" & dbPlanFile & "; " & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES; """ & _
"Persist Security Info=False; " & _
"Jet OLEDB:Database Password=v83;Prompt=3;"
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1; """
```

I suspect I am either using the wrong drivers or there is something important I am missing in the connection string.

Comment: That first string seems valid, which errors do you get? Specifying _Excel_ in the connection strive is for opening Excel files, so that second one is nonsense

Comment: Also worth noting that there is really no such thing as a "32 bit Access MDB file" (or a "64-bit Access ACCDB file"). A given MDB/ACCDB file will be identical regardless of whether it is created with 32-bit Access or 64-bit Access. The ODBC/OLEDB *drivers* required to manipulate those files from an external application have a specific "bitness" (which must match the "bitness" of the application that uses them), but there is no "bitness" to the MDB/ACCDB files themselves.

Comment: connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=v83;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & dbPlanFile & ";" 

Error:
Unrecognized database format 'C:\Plans\Bank.mdb'

Other than the 64 bit Office 365 I have installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe.